# Blockchain Ethereum applications

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'm trying to develop a simple decentralized application on windows, using the tutorial of Ethereum-"DAPPS for beginners". It needs three pieces of software: Alethzero, Mist and Mix. I'm having a lot of problems in different levels because apparently, they stopped working with Alethzero and Mix. Are there any alternatives? Is there a solution to develop a good Dapp, where I can see the most important parts of a blockchain? For instance the mining and the security system?

Answer (score 1):

You should look for another tutorial. Alethzero and Mix are discontinued for more than a year now. And the C++ Ethereum project is pretty much dead except for the Solidity language.

For alternatives, check the [DApp tutorial for Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Tutorial-Part-I) or [How to build serverless applicatoins for Mist](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/12/build-server-less-applications-mist/).

Answer (score 0):

To get started with ethereum Dapp on windows you need below things

1. Geth command line tool available on ethereum.org site.
2. Visual studio 2015 with solidity extension installed  or VS code with solidity extension or you can use online Solidity compiler as editor.
3. Any web application framework Angularjs, reactjs etc .
4. Web3.js library to communicate with ethereum blockchain.
5. Finally very important is setting up the private chain locally , follow below blog written by me for private network setup

[Ethereum blockchain Private network setup, multi node / multi miner](http://mahesh-developernotes.blogspot.com/2017/03/ethereum-blockchain-private-setup-geth.html)